# How can I reduce the number of classes used for RPC calls?

Tags: c#, prism

I'm currently working on a project that uses a custom server protocol for an API which functions much like RPC. To fit the PRISM architecture though, the number of classes and amount of boilerplate to support these functions are ballooning rapidly. Please note I inherited this codebase, and I don't have enough time to go around rewriting too much right now.

Basically the problem is that when the repository is making a call to the service proxy, we have to pass through parameters via JSON to the server, which means we need a RequestParameters object to serialize. We then receive a response which doesn't always look the same, so most calls have unique ResponseParameters as well. Finally, there's also an event structure, where an event is returned from the server but is distinguished by a text field, meaning we then have to write an event router, route each event to its specific section, and then route it further from there, and create a unique event class for each event.

In this fashion, if I want to make a call that returns the result as an event, I need to make two methods, three classes, and add the event entry to the appropriate event router, and most of those classes are time consuming boilerplate.

How can I change the structure of this to address the class bloat and improve the routing concept?

Answer (score 1):

Some techniques that help with this short of a major overhaul:

1. Abstract the boilerplate into base classes that use generics
2. Code generation (via T4 built into VS or a 3rd party tool like
   PostSharp)
3. Within certain scopes, define things as "dynamic"
   rather than creating classes for them (your event code/router seem
   like a good candidate for this)

Comment: I'll add a #4 for anyone who comes by - callbacks can drastically reduce work over publishing and catching custom events built from objects.